# asp.net website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I deploy my project to `inetpub/wwwroot/` directory, and trying to run my index.aspx file though browser, it shows this error:

```
Line 44:        < authentication mode="Windows" / >
```

```
Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\conversion\web.config    Line: 44 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615; ASP.NET     Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

I don't know what the problem is. How can this be fixed?

IIS version 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in your web.config file and and change the authentication mode to `"None"`

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

You can read more about authentication modes and how they work [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: showing same error for this also 
`Line 42: ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. Line 43: --> Line `
`44: <authentication mode="None"/> Line 45: <!-- Line 46: The `
`<customErrors> section enables configuration Source File: `
`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\conversion\web.config Line: 44 `

Comment: Try going to the authentication section of your IIS and making sure you don't have authentication setup for that directory. You can also try removing the `<authentication mode="">` section entirely.

Comment: Remove the entire authentication tag. Just completely delete it and see if it gives you a different error.